# How to find unused items in the Content folder in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I'm setting up a new Umbraco site to replace an older ASP.Net site.

The old site is riddled with old content that isn't linked to anymore. I want to prevent the same thing from happening on the new Umbraco site.

Is there a good way of finding unused items in Umbraco's Content folder (not Templates or Document Types)?

If that's not feasible, is there a way to keep content owners from creating a bunch of content pages and abandoning them instead of deleting them?

Comment: When you say "linked to", do you mean by other websites? And what would you class is unused items - things that aren't published, or that haven't been updated in X days/months?

Comment: By "Linked to" I mean linked to from within my own website. Unused would mean not linked to from within my own website.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question, but from an SEO point of view an old page of content has plenty of power & I wouldn't delete it if possible.

I don't know of an umbraco package that will tell you which pages don't have links - but Google will tell you.  If you want to know what links to www.example.com/oldpage.html then type the following into Google:

```
link:www.example.com/oldpage.html
```

(https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en)

I wouldn't delete old content (unless it is now plainly wrong) I'd keep all the old content & tidy it away:

- Create a folder under home called something like 'archive'
- Move all your dead content there
- Use a 301 redirection package or change urlrewriting.config in case there are any external links to these dead pages as the old urls will now return 404 errors
- Make sure that the sitemap contains links to these new archive pages

You will now have cleaned up the structure, but without losing any SEO value.